# Make WCF client static or use dispose method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, idisposable, wcf-client

I am developing a website in `MVC ASP.NET` that uses a WCF service. I'm using WCF client in controller like that

```
Public class Home : Controller
{
    private ServiceClient _client = new ServiceClient();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

So I think about 2 options that I have to define it:

1- Make client object static

```
private static ServiceClient _client = new ServiceClient();
```

2- use `IDisposable.Dispose`

```
Public class Home : Controller, IDisposable
{
    private ServiceClient _client = new ServiceClient();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _client.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

What is the best option for the performance ?

Answer (score 0):

Both options are irrelevant from the performance point of view. Only creating WCF channel factories is performance "expensive". But the `ServiceClient` inherits from the `ClientBase`, which does the channel factory caching. So creating clients is cheap and that's actually the correct approach: create the client, use it, dispose it immediately.

The second option would therefore be correct, if not a flaw in the WCF client desing. The flaw causes you cannot rely on the client's `Dispose` method to handle the channel's fault state correctly. This issue for sure has been covered somewhere else in SO. But in short, here's how I usually create and dispose the WCF client:

```
var client = new ServiceClient();
var success = false;
try
{
    // call client's methods
    client.Close();
    success = true;
}
finally
{
    if (!success)
    {
        client.Abort();
    }
}
```